# Terms "Systematic", "disciplined", "quantifieable" in the IEEE software engineering definition

Tags: definition, ieee

The IEEE defines software engineering in the following way:

> (1) The application  of  a  systematic,  disciplined,  quantifiable 
>   approach  to  the  development,  operation,  and  maintenance  of 
>   software;  that  is,  the  application of  engineering to
>   software.
>   Source: http://www.idi.ntnu.no/grupper/su/publ/ese/ieee-se-glossary-610.12-1990.pdf

But what does systematic, disciplined and quantifiable mean in this context? Is there any further explanation from the IEEE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on a dictionary:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/systematic:
having, showing, or involving a system, method, or plan

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disciplined:
having or exhibiting discipline; rigorous

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quantifiable:
to determine, indicate, or express the quantity of.

So, applying software engineering requires the exact execution of method that is precise with quantified steps and exact procedures regarding development, operation and maintenance of software.

or as it is state at the end:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/engineering:
the art or science of making practical application of the knowledge of  sciences, as *computer science*, as in the construction of **software**.  (I changed a little bit this definition) =)

Comment: Thank you. I thought the IEEE had specific meanings of these terms in mind.